# .htaccess RewriteRule with file extension

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, file, mod-rewrite

This question might be a duplicate but i'm trying to do a URL Rewrite by converting :

http://example.com/file.php?f=the_file_name&ext=the_file_extension

to

http://example.com/video2.mp4

I tried the following RewriteRule script but it change also others folders :

`Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+).([^/]+)$ file.php?f=$1&t=$2 [L]`

I couldn't get them work.. What am I doing wrong? and how can I make it work?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dot is special regex symbol and it needs to be escaped:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.([^/]+)$ file.php?f=$1&t=$2 [L,QSA]
```